# With equation of vector fields which are in cylindrical polar coordinates, how to plot 3-D vector field?

Tags: plotting, vector, coordinate-transformation, geometric-transform

I have the equation of vector fields which are in cylindrical polar coordinates. How do I plot 3-D vector field? I never used Mathematica.

**Edit2:**

```
a = 1
v = 1
F = 1    
q = 4*Pi^2*v^2*a^2
Htheta = F*q*2*Pi*v*r/(Pi*a^2*log[1 + q]*(1 + q*r^2/a^2))
Hz = F*q/(Pi*a^2*log[1 + q]*(1 + q*r^2/a^2))
H = TransformedField[
  "Polar" -> "Cartesian", {0, Htheta}, {r, \[Theta]} -> {x, y}]
VectorPlot3D[{H.{1, 0}, H.{0, 1}, z}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, 
  0, 6}, VectorColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors"]
```

This was my code, and I got a black graph.
[image]

Comment: As a start, check the [Plot Field Vectors in 3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/PlotFieldVectorsIn3D.html) documentation and the Related Guides.

Comment: @creidhne Hey, I have edited body, can you help me out from here.

Comment: Mathematica has some quirks, for example, pi is `Pi`, and functions such as log(...) are capitalized with brackets like `Log[...]`. You need to define values for `a`, `q`, `F`, and `v`.

Comment: Also, I would expect Hr to get a three-dimensional vector field

Comment: Resolved thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this was easy, from comments mentioned above:

```
a = 1
v = 1
F = 1
q = 4*Pi^2*v^2*a^2
Htheta = F*q*2*Pi*v*r/(Pi*a^2*Log[1 + q]*(1 + q*r^2/a^2))
Hz = F*q/(Pi*a^2*Log[1 + q]*(1 + q*r^2/a^2))
H = TransformedField[
  "Polar" -> "Cartesian", {0, Htheta}, {r, \[Theta]} -> {x, y}]
VectorPlot3D[{H.{1, 0}, H.{0, 1}, z}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, 
  0, 6}, VectorColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors"]
VectorPlot[{H.{1, 0}, H.{0, 1}}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```